# Fluent NHibernate complex Composite Id's

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying to get the following to work for a few hours now. But I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm using Fluent Nhibernate automapper (and some overrides) to get this structure to work.

```
public class Game:IKeyed<Guid>
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    //properties
}

public class Team : IKeyed<Guid>
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    //Other properties

    public virtual IList<GameTeam> GameTeams { get; set; }
}

public class GameTeam:IKeyed<GameTeamId>
{
    public virtual GameTeamId Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int CurrentRound { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<GameTeamRound> Rounds { get; set; }
}

public class GameTeamId
{
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

    //equals stuff
}

public class GameTeamRound : IKeyed<GameTeamRoundId>
{
    public virtual GameTeamRoundId Id { get; set; }
    //Properties

    public virtual IList<TeamRoundDecision> Decisions { get; set; }
}

public class GameTeamRoundId
{
    public virtual GameTeam GameTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual int RoundNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The GameTeam relation is something I can manage. But the GameTeamRound link is going a bit to far for the moment. :)
I even have a level deeper. But I don't want to make the question more complicated.

I'm using NHibernate to generate my database for me. So I'm starting from my model.
To make this work I'm using some mapping overrides to make sure that these composite keys are working.

```
public class GameTeamOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<GameTeam>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<GameTeam> mapping)
    {
        //mapping.IgnoreProperty(gt => gt.Id);
        mapping.CompositeId(gt => gt.Id)
               .KeyProperty(id => id.Game.Id, "GameId")
               .KeyProperty(id => id.Team.Id, "TeamId");
    }
}

public class GameTeamRoundOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<GameTeamRound>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<GameTeamRound> mapping)
    {
        //mapping.IgnoreProperty(gtr => gtr.Id);
        mapping.CompositeId(gtr => gtr.Id)
               .KeyProperty(id => id.GameTeam.Id.Game.Id, "GameId")
               .KeyProperty(id => id.GameTeam.Id.Team.Id, "TeamId")
               .KeyProperty(id => id.RoundNumber, "RoundId");
    }
}
```

I've tried al sort of things. If you could point me into the right direction, that would be great. :)

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Why the extra `Id` classes? You should put those properties directly into the respective entities. Furthermore: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: That's because I'm using a repository pattern that relies on a single property with the name Id. That's the best solution that is working for me. The error I get is the following. Could not find a getter for property 'Id' in class 'GameTeamId'

Comment: You should model your infrastructure after the Model, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the extra class for the composite key?
It should be working somehow like this:

Entities:

```
public class Game:IKeyed<Guid>
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    //properties
}

public class Team : IKeyed<Guid>
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    //Other properties

    public virtual IList<GameTeam> GameTeams { get; set; }
}

public class GameTeam:IKeyed<GameTeamId>
{
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    public virtual int CurrentRound { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<GameTeamRound> Rounds { get; set; }
}

public class GameTeamRound : IKeyed<GameTeamRoundId>
{
    public virtual GameTeam GameTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual int RoundNumber { get; set; }
    //Properties

    public virtual IList<TeamRoundDecision> Decisions { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class GameTeamOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<GameTeam>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<GameTeam> mapping)
    {
        mapping.CompositeId()
               .KeyReference(id => id.Game, "GameId")
               .KeyReference(id => id.Team, "TeamId");
    }
}

public class GameTeamRoundOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<GameTeamRound>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<GameTeamRound> mapping)
    {
        mapping.CompositeId()
               .KeyReference(id => id.GameTeam.Game, "GameId")
               .KeyReference(id => id.GameTeam.Team, "TeamId")
               .KeyProperty(id => id.RoundNumber, "RoundId");
    }
}
```

Please note: I am not sure if it even is possible to use this kind of nesting in a composite ID. If not, you would need to add properties for Game and Team and delegate the calls to them to `GameTeam.Game` and `GameTeam.Team` respectivly.

Additionally, please re-consider your design. Composite keys are discouraged for newly written applications. If they can be avoided, avoid them.

Comment: My first thought was to do it without composite keys as you suggest. Maybe that would be the best option. Just to be curious. Why are they discouraged?

Comment: @MatrixCow: They create all sorts of problems, one of which you just witnessed. I am actually not sure if they are discouraged only from an ORM point of view or also from an SQL point of view.

Comment: Ok. :-) thanks alot for the help. I'll just remove the composite keys and continue from there.